# how to use lookup in mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to Join my table this is example of data. I want to join data2 in my data1
where data1Id = data1.id

I try to use `$lookup` but It still get all data

```
const data1 = [
  {
    id: 'ID1'
    name: 1
  }
]

const data2 = [
  {
    data1Id: 'ID1',
    sub_name: 'test'
  },
  {
    data1Id: 'ID1',
    sub_name: 'test'
  },
  {
    data1Id: 'ID3',
    sub_name: 'test'
  }
]


output =  [
  {
    data1Id: 'ID1',
    sub_name: 'test'
  },
  {
    data1Id: 'ID1',
    sub_name: 'test'
  },
 
]
```

here is what I try

```
[
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'data2', 
      'localField': 'data1Id', 
      'foreignField': 'id', 
      'as': 'output'
    }
  }
]
```

this is what is my output look like

```
output = [
  {
    data1Id: 'ID1',
    sub_name: 'test'
  },
  {
    data1Id: 'ID1',
    sub_name: 'test'
  },
  {
    data1Id: 'ID3',
    sub_name: 'test'
  }
]
```

it did not select only data that data1Id is same

Answer (score 0):

I got it because the lookup cannot use objectID so I have to project _id  into string first

```
[
  {
    '$project': {
      '_id': {
        '$toString': '$_id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'data2', 
      'localField': '_id', 
      'foreignField': 'data1Id', 
      'as': 'output'
    }
  }
]
```